# c# date formatting issue with Culture info

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, cultureinfo

I try to format a local date into a string, but based on the local format.
By example, for the 5 May 2020, if I use French, I expected "5 Mai, 2020",
but I got "5 May, 2020" ...

The month name is still in English !

Here is my code to test this:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/saZJ0S

Do you have any idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [DateTime.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) overload that gets CultureInfo parameter as a second argument.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1

So your code would look like (copying from the image you attached):

```
string FormattedPostDate = localDate.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR").DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR")) + ", " + localDate.Year;
```